# Is there any way that multiple select can be applied to deactivate or disable random member in a group?

Tags: tables, accordion, delete

Is there any way that multiple select can be applied to deactivate or disable random member without affecting the group which is also can be deactivated?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a use case for this?